# Universal image loader 1.9.1 wrong image on display

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I was using older version of image loader and all was ok.
When I started with new version I have problem with funny images display on my all devices.

Images was loaded from assets.

[image]

My image loader options:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .build();


options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5))
            .build();
```

And my `ImageView` in xml.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/row_object_image_height"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
```

Comment: i checked from github but working fine it seems, i used https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: this problem is when I use RoundedBitmapDisplayer

Comment: Do you have problems if not use `RoundedBitmapDisplayer`?

Comment: I don't have problem without roundedBitmap.